# Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ubiquity.desktop does not launch in test mode

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, .desktop, ubiquity

I am trying to create a RAID for two SSD and following this guidance [Install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299978/install-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios)

I can enter the Ubuntu trial mode and create the partitions.

I get stuck with Step 3 - Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS icon from desktop. Nothing happens when I click it. I found a suggestion here - [Ubuntu live: ubiquity.desktop (alias "Install <MyDistro>") is not launched](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349665/ubuntu-live-ubiquity-desktop-alias-install-mydistro-is-not-launched?newreg=16be65fac11c49de81c0e3d0d541e6c3) but running the installation file as root didn't work for me either. Nor does changing the code of the ubiquity file into

```
Exec=sudo --preserve-env=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS,XDG_RUNTIME_DIR ubiquity gtk_ui
```

Then my error message is
--preserve-env=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS,XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: Command not found

Alternatively, I tried to run the ubiquity command from terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-gtk
ubiquity --desktop gtk_ui
```

but nothing happens and after a while the error message is "Failed to wait for daemon to reply: Connection timed out".

Appreciate any suggestions to resolve this.

I am using an ISO file from a USB which worked for the initial installation (before attempting to install a RAID) and it also worked to get into the test mode of Ubuntu.